# Word Wrap wrong when changing strings in viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I write an app that using localizations string. I use storyboard to draw UIControllers, and reference UILabels outlet to source code. I change text in **viewWillAppear** for assigning localize string to **UILabel.text**.

My labels in storyboard have been input default strings that have right word wrap. But when I change label's text in viewWillAppear, the strings will wrap words at wrong position.

I have set UILabel with 0 numbersOfLine, LineBreak mode is word wrap, increate label height... but not work.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // TEXT
    commentLabel.text = "*Please connect both devices to the same Wi-Fi network."
}
```

In storyboard with default string, it looks like: 
[image: In storyboard]

But after changing text in viewWillAppear, it will show as below: 
[image: After changing text in viewWillAppear]
the "same" will be break into "sa" and "me"!!

Could someone help me?

-- 
Update:

Constraits. "Loading Text" is "Connect to %Device Name%"
[image: Imgur]

--
Update:

If I don't change text in viewWillAppear, it shows normal as below. So I think it might not that problem about constraints or layout?
[image: Imgur]

Comment: Make the text justified.

Comment: change the font size

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure you had set these things to make it multiline with word wrap

First Make sure you didn't added any fix height constraint for your label or your superview

Second Make sure `Number of lines` is set to `0`

Third select `Work wrap` option from the `Line break` option and also allow `Autoshrink` if the size of font is bigger then the its frame so the font will automatically adjust regarding minimum size.

[image]

> Note: You can also add `"\n"` to start from a new line

```
commentLabel.text = "*Please connect both devices to the \n same Wi-Fi network."
```

Comment: Sorry but I can't change font size cause of design. Add "\n" to break line might not show what I want for different iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

set the the leading and trailing constraints and add a fixed width and height to it, considering the fact its a hardcoded label. You could use the below link to fix it programatically.

https://newfivefour.com/swift-ios-add-view-programmatically-autolayout-NSLayoutConstraint.html

Comment: Btw you don't need to set fixed width if you're setting leading and trailing constraints. Fixed height is also useless if you have `numberOfLines` of label set to 0. So, he actually needs just leading, trailing, top and bottom (optional)

Comment: I add bottom constraint but nothing change.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you have added the constraints correctly, specially bottom constraint of label to bottom of the view.

Comment: I try to add the bottom constraint but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no constraint error, the result does not make sense.

So in your design interface you have a different one like iPhone XS than that in your real simulator or device like iPhone XR. Please make sure Both are same so that what you get is what you design.